# Error in shell bracket test when string is a left-parenthesis

Tags: shell, test

I used to be confident about the fact that quoting strings is always a good practice in order to avoid having the shell parsing it.

Then I came across this:

```
$ x='('
$ [ "$x" = '1' -a "$y" = '1' ]
bash: [: `)' expected, found 1
```

Trying to isolate the problem, getting the same error:

```
$ [ '(' = '1' -a '1' = '1' ]
bash: [: `)' expected, found 1
```

I solved the problem like this:

```
[ "$x" = '1' ] && [ "$y" = '1' ]
```

Still I need to know what's going on here.

Comment: As a workaround, in bash, you can use `[[ "$x" = '1' && "$y" = '1' ]]`

Comment: [The POSIX specification for test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) explicitly describes `-a` and `-o` as obsolescent for this reason (which is what the `[OB]` superscript next to their specification means). If you wrote `[ "$x" = 1 ] && [ "$y" = 1 ]` instead, you'd be fine, and would be well within the realm of well-defined/standardized behavior.

Comment: This is why people used to use `[ "x$x" = "x1" ]` to prevent arguments being misinterpreted as operators.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Hey, you condensed my answer to a single sentence, not fair! :) If one uses a POSIX shell like `dash` rather than Bash, it's still a useful practice.

Comment: I want to thanks everyone taking the time to answer my question, really appreciated guys :) ! I also want to thanks for the vital editing done to my question. Entering this forum sometimes gives me the same thrill of escaping from Alcatraz, wrong move means your life. Anyway I really wish my Thanks will reach you before this comment gets deleted

Answer (score 25):

This is a very obscure corner case that one might consider a bug in how the test `[` built-in is defined; however, it does match the behaviour of the actual `[` binary available on many systems. As far as I can tell, it only affects certain cases and a variable having a value that matches a `[` operator like `(`, `!`, `=`, `-e`, and so on.

Let me explain why, and how to work around it in Bash and POSIX shells.

---

Explanation:

Consider the following:

```
x="("
[ "$x" = "(" ] && echo yes || echo no
```

No problem; the above yields no error, and outputs `yes`. This is how we expect stuff to work. You can change the comparison string to `'1'` if you like, and the value of `x`, and it'll work as expected.

Note that the actual `/usr/bin/[` binary behaves the same way. If you run e.g. `'/usr/bin/[' '(' = '(' ']'` there is no error, because the program can detect that the arguments consist of a single string comparison operation.

The bug occurs when we *and* with a second expression. It does not matter what the second expression is, as long as it is valid. For example,

```
[ '1' = '1' ] && echo yes || echo no
```

outputs `yes`, and is obviously a valid expression; but, if we combine the two,

```
[ "$x" = "(" -a '1' = '1' ] && echo yes || echo no
```

Bash rejects the expression if and only if `x` is `(` or `!`.

If we were to run the above using the actual `[` program, i.e.

```
'/usr/bin/[' "$x" = "(" -a '1' = '1' ] && echo yes || echo no
```

the error would be understandable: since the shell does the variable substitutions, the `/usr/bin/[` binary only receives parameters `(` `=` `(` `-a` `1` `=` `1` and the terminating `]`, it understandably fails to parse whether the open parentheses start a sub-expression or not, there being an *and*  operation involved. Sure, parsing it as two string comparisons is possible, but doing it greedily like that might cause issues when applied to proper expressions with parenthesized sub-expressions.

The problem, really, is that the shell `[` built-in behaves the same way, as if it expanded the value of `x` before examining the expression.

(These ambiguities, and others related to variable expansion, were a large reason why Bash implemented and now recommends using the `[[ ... ]]` test expressions instead.)

---

The workaround is trivial, and often seen in scripts using older `sh` shells. You add a "safe" character, often `x`, in front of the strings (both values being compared), to ensure the expression is recognized as a string comparison:

```
[ "x$x" = "x(" -a "x$y" = "x1" ]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the behaviour of the `[` built-in a bug.  If anything, it's an inherent design flaw.  `[[` is a shell *keyword*, not just a built-in command, so it gets to look at things before quote-removal, and actually override the usual word-splitting.  e.g. `[[ $x == 1 ]]` doesn't need to use `"$x"`, because a `[[` context is different from normal.  Anyway, this is how `[[` is able to avoid the pitfalls of `[`.  POSIX requires `[` to behave the way it does, and bash is mostly POSIX compliant even without `--posix`, so changing `[` into a keyword is unattractive.

Comment: Your workaround is not recommended by POSIX.  Just use two calls to `[`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Quite right; good point. (I perhaps should have used *designed* instead of *defined* in my first paragraph, but `[`'s behaviour being burdened by history predating POSIX, I chose the latter word instead.) I do personally avoid using `[[` in my example scripts, but only because it is an exception to the quoting recommendation I always harp about (since omitting quotes is the most common reason for script bugs I see), and I haven't thought of a simple paragraph to explain why `[[` is an exception to the rules, without making my quoting recommendation suspect.

Comment: @Wildcard: No. POSIX does *not recommend against this practice*, and that's what matters. Just because an authority does not happen to recommend this practice, does not make this bad. Indeed, as I point out, this is historical practice used in `sh` scripts, well predating POSIX standardization. Using parenthesized subexpressions and `-a` and `-o` logical operators in tests/`[` is more efficient that relying on expression chaining (via `&&` and `||`); it's just that on current machines, the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @Wildcard: However, I do personally prefer to chain the test expressions using `&&` and `||`, but the reason is, it makes it easier for us humans to maintain (read, understand, and modify if/when necessary) them without introducing bugs. So, I'm not criticising your suggestion, but only the reasoning behind the suggestion. (For very similar reasons, the `.LT.`, `.GE.`, etc. comparison operators in FORTRAN 77 got much more human-friendly versions `<`, `>=`, etc. in later versions.)

Comment: It's not about `[...]` but about `-a/-o` operator.

Comment: @cuonglm: What? The `-a` and `-o` operators are only defined for the `[` (and `test`) built-in commands for Bash. Saying that the question is not about the built-in command, but about its operator, is like saying that whether it is raining or not has nothing to do with the weather. Makes zero sense. Thanks for the downvote, nevertheless.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: not sure what you mean. The weird behavior is nothing about `[` or `/usr/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/[` but about their `-a/-o` operator. You can read the POSIX spec about them.

Comment: @cuonglm: Did you even read my answer? The `-a` and `-o` operators are only defined for the `[` or `test` commands, so *of course* it has everything to do with the command! Simply put, due to the historical baggage of how the command evaluates its parameters, it fails to parse expressions correctly if the variable expands to an operator, and there is more than one logical sub-expression in it. The `-a`/`-o` operators are incidental; this occurs with e.g. parentheses, too. Try `[ '(' "$x" = "1" ')' ]` with `x="("` or `x="!"`, for example; it too fails with an error.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That's the point I said it's nothing about `[` or `test` command or `[` builtin. `[ '(' "$x" = "1" ')' ]` is different case because you passed 4 arguments to `[...]`. Read the spec again about the number of arguments passed to `[...]`.

Comment: @cuonglm: You commented that *"It's not about `[...]` but about `-a/-o` operator."* and downvoted this answer. I showed you that the problem is the behaviour of the `[` (and `test`) command, and in my answer explain exactly what happens with the expressions OP is using, and how to work around them. In a comment, I also show that this happens even without `-a` or `-o` operators, just by parenthesizing the expression. Instead of admitting your error, you claim that's somehow a different case. I say no: it is exactly the behaviour I explained in my answer.

Comment: If anyone had pointed out that I neglected to mention that POSIX.1-2008 has [obsoleted parentheses and `-a` and `-o` operators](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) -- meaning POSIX.1 may remove them in a future version, and recommends against their use --, as Charles Duffy pointed out in a comment to the original question, I'd understand the argument and downvote, and would be persuaded to edit my answer to include a note about that. I just get irate when high-reputation members make nonsensical claims without backing them up, and never admit to being wrong.

Answer (score 11):

`[` aka `test` sees:

```
 argc: 1 2 3 4  5 6 7 8
 argv: ( = 1 -a 1 = 1 ]
```

`test` accepts subexpressions in parentheses; so it thinks that the left parenthesis opens a subexpression and is trying to parse it; the parser sees `=` as the first thing in the subexpression and thinks that it is an implicit string-length test, so it is happy; the subexpression should then be followed by a right parenthesis, and instead the parser finds `1` instead of `)`. And it complains.

When `test` has exactly three arguments, and the middle argument is one of the recognized operators, it applies that operator to the 1st and 3rd arguments without looking for subexpressions in parentheses.

For the full details look at `man bash`, search for `test expr`.

Conclusion: The parsing algorithm used by `test` is complicated. Use only simple expressions and use the *shell* operators `!`, `&&` and `||` to combine them.